# MySQL/MariaDB, does commit() write to disk if there were no changes? Concerned about Raspberries SD card life

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, innodb, commit

I'm a little worried about my Raspberry Pi's SD-card life.
On the Raspberry, there's a MySQL(MariaDB)-server running.
A program of mine is reading from the database every second,
then looks something up on the internet and only rarely,
when something happens, it's going to write to the database.

I used to use commit() only once every 5 minutes, but apparently if I don't commit,
the program doesn't see changes from other programs even though those are from tables
it doesn't write to.

1) Concerns about a Raspberries-SD-card's life are all over the internet, so my question is,
how to best call commit()?

2) If it just reads from the database but doesn't change anything, will commit even access the disk?
Is there a way to see the new changes without commiting?

3) And if I do have to commit every second in order to see the changes in time, how bad is it?

PS: I'm using Python3 with mysql-connector, an 8 GB SD with the OS the raspberry imager program recommended to me

Comment: How many DWPD can your SD card support? Some cards handle writes very badly, others are perfectly fine. If you're really concerned, use a USB-connected mixed-use SSD.

Comment: At least you'll have your backup, in case anything does go wrong

Comment: What is writing to the database?  Aren't you contradicting yourself to say "it just reads".

Comment: Every second the program does: 1) READ the database in order to know what it's supposed to ask the website 2) Asks the WEBSITE for that information 3) IF that information has CHANGED it will WRITE to the database. So short, it reads every second but only rarely writes something. Like at the very most a couple hundred rows a day.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess since it's just a couple hundred writings a day, it's totally fine.
But why have you guys all answered in the comments?
Who am I gonna pick as best answer?